# GC unable to remove KafkaStreams in ERROR state object from heap due to registered metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

There is a `KafkaStreams` application(kafka-streams version 2.4.0) that subscribes and unsubscribes to/from the topic at runtime. During unsubscribe `KafkaStrams` is getting closed with:

```
KafkaStreams.close();
KafkaStreams.cleanUp();
```

But even closed such `KafkaStream` is not eligible to GC and after some period of time and number of unsubscriptions application crashes with OOM.

Heapdump analysis showed that those streams are in Termination state - `ERROR`, `PENDING_SHUTDOWN`, `NOT_RUNNING` have GC root in `JmxMBeanServer` with `JmxReported.KafkaMbean` stored there.

Is it expected that some metrics stays after stream termination inside `JmxMBeanServer` and if yes how to clean them up to make `KafkaStreams` objects GC eligieble?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Metrics should be de-registered to not leak memory. Can you please file a ticket?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax after some investigation found that next JMX metrics aren't unregistered
kafka.consumer:type=consumer-metrics,client-id=%clientId%-restore-consumer
kafka.consumer:type=consumer-metrics,client-id=%clientId%-consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed consumer metrics aren't de-registered and there is an already fixed issue in Kafka project - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9306.

Upgrading `kafka-clients` to version `2.4.1` fixed the issue.